# UIActionSheet firstOtherButtonIndex set incorrectly

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiactionsheet

I'm displaying an UIActionSheet on the iPad this way:

```
_actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose action"
                                           delegate:(id<UIActionSheetDelegate>)self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                             destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

if (special_case) {
    _actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex = [_actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Discard Action"];
}

[_actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Action One"];
[_actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Action Two"];
_actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [_actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

[_actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:self.myActionButton animated:YES];
```

While both `cancelButtonIndex` and `destructiveButtonIndex` work fine, the weird thing is that in actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex: I'm getting `firstOtherButtonIndex` set to `-1`, which is obviously wrong because my `Action One` button has an index of `1`, while `Action Two` has an index of `2`.

Obviously the whole point of the above is to only display the destructive button only in a special case (otherwise I would have passed all titles in the init call and probably things would have been sweet).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firstOtherButtonIndex` is probably set only in the `initWithTitle` method. You have to set it manually if you are adding buttons manually. The problem can be also caused by the fact that you are adding the cancel button after adding the other buttons. Normally the indices of destructive and cancel buttons are lower than `firstOtherButtonIndex`.

What about doing it the easy way?

```
_actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose action"
                                           delegate:(id)self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                             destructiveButtonTitle:(special_case ? @"Discard" : nil)
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Action One", @"Action Two", nil];
```

Comment: Right, I thought `firstOtherButtonIndex` wasn't supposed to be set manually.  As for the order in which I'm adding buttons, I understood that's the HIG-compliant way (destructive first, other buttons then, and cancel last).  Yes, the indices of destructive and cancel are indeed lower (-1 and 0), so they don't match the order in which I'm adding the buttons.

Comment: The alert sheet should know from the indices which button is cancel and show it as the last button. However I think the API is not perfect and doesn't suppose that destructive and cancel buttons are added dynamically. They should be always specified in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Obviously your "easy way" above makes most sense in this case (I only had everything done dynamically because I also have a variable number of otherButtons).